# Windows 2008 - Time Sync

Tags: windows, time, ntp

What is the threshold in Windows 2008 when the local clock differs from an NTP source and it will not synchronize?

For example, if the local time is off > 2 days, will NTP still sync? Is there a value that can be tweaked?

No Domain/Active Directory involved here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the maximum correction in Windows Server 2008 is 48 hours. You can tweak this value by altering the `MaxPosPhaseCorrection` and `MaxNegPhaseCorrection` REG_DWORD values in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters`. These values set the maximum number of seconds of time offset that can be corrected for. [Microsoft has more detail in their article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884776), including information about older operating systems, but this is the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

On your registry.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters\NtpServer
It usually points to time.windows.com

You can configure an authoritative time server [following this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042)
For the rest of the values involved [follow this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884776)